# Updating Knockout observables through jQuery event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, knockout.js

I understand that using jQuery event handlers with Knockout is poor practice but, for the time being, I would like to continue on this path I started.  I am looking for clarification on how I can update the view model with observables by using the click event in jQuery as I have laid out in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8ueg0yc/2/).

The intended behavior is: click a color button (i.e. `Red, Green, Blue`) and then click `UPDATE!` to show data for that respective color.  For example, clicking Red -> Update will spit out "red flower sun" in the DOM. Then clicking Blue -> Update will produce "blue sky ocean".

I believe the problem is with my observables and the `with: colors` data-bind, but I don't fully understand why. This has basically been a 2-day crash course on Knockout for me and I feel like a lot of this should come much easier than it has.

Kindly show me the light!

### HTML

```
<div data-bind="with: colors">
  <h4 data-bind="text: name"></h4>
  <div data-bind="foreach: things">
    <span data-bind="text: $data" />
  </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
function Sample(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.colors = ko.observableArray();
  self.currentColor = ko.observable();

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}

var sample = new Sample({
  "colors": [{
    "name": "red",
    "things": ["flower", "sun"]
  }, {
    "name": "green",
    "things": ["tree", "money"]
  }, {
    "name": "blue",
    "things": ["sky", "ocean"]
  }]
});

ko.applyBindings(sample);

var clicked;
$("button").on("click", function() {
  clicked = this.className;
});

$(".update").on("click", function() {
  if (clicked === "red") {
    // ???    
  }
  if (clicked === "green") {
    // ???    
  }
  if (clicked === "blue") {
    // ???    
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle to match up what you would like to have.
But I hope you will really disregard this way.
Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8ueg0yc/3/).

What I did there is find the color which has a `name` of the `clicked` variable.

```
$(".update").on("click", function() {
  var foundColor = sample.colors().find(function(color){
    return color.name() === clicked;
  });
  sample.currentColor(foundColor);
});
```

And the value for your with binding should be the currentColor and not your observable array.

```
<div data-bind="with: currentColor">
```

BUT still, this is not the right way to go, you should read on [click](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) binding, it will get you started and will have a cleaner implementation on this, and a shorter one.

Answer (score 1):

If  you want to render all colors, you'll have to use the `foreach` binding. This is sort of like an automated `with` binding for each item in your `colors` array:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: colors"> ... </div>
```

I don't think you should use jQuery for even handling when you're using knockout, so I'll explain how to use the `click` binding.

The basic layout of the click binding is:

```
click: function(currentlyBoundData, event) { /* ... */ }
```

This means that, when you use it with a `foreach` binding, it send the clicked data along with the click event.

Let's first add a click handler to your viewmodel:

```
self.clickHandler = function(clickedItem, event) {
  console.log(clickedItem);
};
```

Now, attach this handler method to clicks on each of your colors:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: colors">
  <h4 data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.clickHandler"></h4>
</div>
```

Notice the `$parent`: it links to the data-bind context at the `foreach` level, which is the `Sample` viewmodel.

Now that you've made a single method that can be reused by all colors, you can code the remaining logic:

1. Knowing that you set an observable by passing an argument to it,
2. And knowing that the `click` binding passes the clicked item as the first argument

We can directly bind an observable to a `click` method

3. like so: `data-bind="click: $parent.currentColor"`

Finally, you'll need an `update` method that:

1. Gets `currentColor` by calling it without arguments: `self.currentColor()`
2. And puts it in a new observable, named `selectedColor`: `self.selectedColor(self.currentColor())`

```js
function Sample(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.colors = ko.observableArray();
  self.currentColor = ko.observable();
  self.selectedColor = ko.observable();

  self.updateColor = function() {
    self.selectedColor(self.currentColor());
  };

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}

var sample = new Sample({
  "colors": [{
    "name": "red",
    "things": ["flower", "sun"]
  }, {
    "name": "green",
    "things": ["tree", "money"]
  }, {
    "name": "blue",
    "things": ["sky", "ocean"]
  }]
});

ko.applyBindings(sample);
```

```css
.selected {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: colors">
  <h4 data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.currentColor, css: {'selected' : $parent.currentColor() === $data}"></h4>
</div>

<button data-bind="click: updateColor">load last clicked</button>

<div data-bind="with: selectedColor">
  Selection: <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
</div>
```

Comment: While this did not match my particular use-case, this is an exceptionally detailed and instructive answer. Thank you.